# Is it possible to pass through a backend url endpoint that is relative to that url through an Azure Function Proxy or perhaps api management

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management, azure-function-app-proxy, azure-functions-proxies

As of now, from what I see, the only way to use Azure Function Proxy is to re-route an existing api is to call upon that api directly. For example:

Backend URL

`https://gateway-api.com/api/getSomething`

Route Template

`/api`

Proxy URL

`https://gateway.azurewebsites.net/api`

What I want is to have the Backend URL pass through any endpoint relative to the main endpoint.

Effectively this:

Backend URL

`https://gateway-api.com/*` or i even tried this `https://gateway-api.com/{*restOfPath}`

This way, any api's that follow the core domain URL will still work as expected.

Here is a re-write of the example above:

Backend URL 2

`https://gateway-api.com/*`

Route Template 2

`/*`

Proxy URL 2

`https://gateway.azurewebsites.net/api/getSomething`

When I do this I can't get it to work or even reach the debuger to log anything.

Is this possible and if not would this be something Azure API Management would be able to accomplish?

Comment: Have you checked out Azure Front Door?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide your configuration file? this is mine:

**Proxies.json:**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
  "proxies": {
    "proxy1": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "methods": [ "GET" ],
        "route": "/{test}"
      },
      "backendUri": "http://localhost:7071/abc/Function1"
    }
  }
}
```

**host.json:**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "routePrefix": "abc"
    }
  },
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the backend url and proxy of my function:

[image]

Both of them works fine.

If you change route template, I think the backend url will not have `/api` unless you give the `/api` to routePrefix.

Any way, please show the file about how to configure proxy and route template.

Comment: I don't understand. This isn't what I was askinig. I know how to make the proxy work. that's not my question

Comment: @ChristianMatthew Can you explain about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfoYp.png)? I am sorry to misunderstanding. I'm not sure what do you mean. Can you explain about this?

Comment: that's ok if you reread the question the ask is how can i forward the url to any backend url. essentially that is what I am asking

Comment: @ChristianMatthew Do you mean hitting any other backend URL you want to hit through a proxy URL? Do you mean this?